# What is the gi.repository in python?

Tags: python, repository, python3

I see from a lot of tutorials that in python the statement "from gi.repository" is used to import lots of different things, like gtk, etc...

What library is it?

Is it related to GitHub? Does it import from GitHub?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`gi.repository` is the Python module for PyGObject (which stands for Python `GObject` introspection) which holds Python bindings and support for the GTK+ 3 toolkit and for the GNOME apps.

See [Projects/PyGObject on the GNOME Wiki](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/PyGObject).

It has nothing to do with GitHub.

Answer (score 7):

It has nothing to do with github.

It is the Python API for GObject Introspection (gi). The *repository* portion is related to the repository of bindings available via GObject Introspection (girepository).

Importing bindings via this method is what replaces the old straight Python bindings for *gobject*, *glib*, *gtk* and similar libraries.